# How to clone components with usestate hook, so they will change independent from each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
   const Section = ({ text, changeFn }) => {
  return(
    <>
      <Content text={text} changeFn={changeFn}/>
      <Content text={text} changeFn={changeFn}/>
      <Content text={text} changeFn={changeFn}/>
    </>
  )
}
const Content = ({ changeFn, text }) => {
  const [ textCont, setText ] =useState('text')
  return(
    <>
      <div>{textCont}</div>
      <button onClick={changeFn}>Edit</button>
    </>
  )
}
const Form = ({ changeFn, setContent }) => {
  let inputRef = useRef()
  const applyChangefn = () => {
    setContent(inputRef.current.value)
    changeFn()
  }
  return(
    <>
      <input ref={inputRef}/>
      <button onClick={applyChangefn}>Save</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

I want to make a component which exists as example with its own usestate in Content component.
Then i want to send it multiplied by 3 times into Section component.
First question is how to send props between sibling components
Second question is how to make 3 same components which have its own useState state. I mean 3 same components with independent usestate.

Comment: You need to start with deciding where your state is going to live. A form with three editable fields should keep the state in the form component, which means you need a state array of size 3, then send down the value and setter to each field component as props. Each field having its own state isn't useful here. Also see here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: but what to do if i want to use functional component , not class? i mean how to do it with hooks

Comment: How to do what exactly? `const [texts, setTexts] = useState(["", "", ""]);`. Now look up how to properly update a state array.